# Move column to last in awk

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I would like to move a specified column (the 2nd) to the last column position. 
I have multiple large tab-delimited files containing variable numbers of columns and rows. But, column 2 in all needs to be last. Another way to put it is that I want the order to be 1,3-last,2.

From this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 ... Column W ColumnX
1 2 3 ... W X
a b c ... apples oranges
```

To this:

```
1 3 ... W X 2
a c ... apples oranges b
```

I'm newish to awk. From reading other threads, I've copied and tried various things like this with no success.

```
#doesn't reorder columns

cut -d $'\t' -f1,3-,2 file.in > file.out


#doesn't work and I don't really understand the for(i...) stuff copied from elsewhere:
cat file.in | awk -F'\t' '{print $1,for(i=3;i<=NF;++i) $i,$2}' > file.out
```

help?

Any pointers to threads/links that explain in simple educational terms what's going on with the for(i...) part would be appreciated as well. I get the gist, not the syntax.

Comment: The reason you don't understand the `for(i...) stuff` is that it's nonsense as written. Do not refer to wherever you copied it from in future. A `for` loop in awk works the same as a `for` loop in C or any other Algol based language.

Comment: My fault. I assume it was appropriate for where ever I found it, but lack of understanding and exploratory copy/paste on my part likely turned it into nonsense. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {a=$2; for (i=2;i<NF; i++) $i=$(i+1); $NF=a}1' file
1       3       W       X       2
a       c       apples  oranges b
```

Which is the same as

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {a=$2; for (i=2;i<NF; i++) $i=$(i+1); $NF=a; print}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` set input and output field separator as tab.
- `a=$2` store the 2nd value.
- `for (i=2;i<NF; i++) $i=$(i+1)` move every value to the next one.
- `$NF=a` set last value as the 2nd, which we stored.
- `1` is a true condition that implies the default `awk` behaviour: `{print $0}`.

Comment: The `1` at the end is just an always-true condition that causes the line to be printed.  Handy for playing code-golf with Awk, but outside of such games I prefer clarity over concision - a simple `;print` inside the braces, for example.

Comment: @MarkReed sometimes that `1` is very handy. But you are right that it is not that clear. Updated with an alternative version containing `print`.

Comment: @MarkReed you can't prefer clarity over conciseness because conciseness IS clarity (with brevity). In this case, the thing I like about `1` is not what it brings to a given script but that it drives home 2 very important points that many awk newbies struggle with - the condition/action structure of the language, and the default action of `print $0`. If you don't understand those points you cant use awk effectively so either you already understand `1` and there's no problem with seeing it in a script, or you need to learn it in which case thank goodness you saw it in a script.

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down for me. I can see I wasn't thinking efficiently about the problem. I was viewing it as listing columns in order that I want to print, rather than reassigning all and then printing all. Lots to learn.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ cat file
Column1 Column2 Column3 ...     ColumnW ColumnX
1       2       3       ...     W       X
a       b       c       ...     apples  oranges

$ awk '{print gensub(/([\t][^\t]+)(.*)/,"\\2\\1","")}' file
Column1 Column3 ...     ColumnW ColumnX Column2
1       3       ...     W       X       2
a       c       ...     apples  oranges b
```

Comment: I'm sure if you just thought about it for a few mins you'd get it. It's really not very complicated or even interesting it's just looking for the first tab followed by non-tabs `([\t][^\t]+)` and moving the string matching that pattern to after the rest `(.*)` by referencing them as `\\1` and `\\2`. You could actually do this with `sed` just as easily.

Comment: Be noted, gensub() function is in gnu awk.

Comment: Hence my opening sentence `With GNU awk for gensub():`

Answer (score 0):

using sed

```
sed -r 's/\W+(\w*)(.*)/\2\t\1/' file
```

Comment: `-r` doesn't exist in Mac OS

Comment: If Mac OS has GNU sed aka `gsed` then this answer could be changed to `gsed -r ...`.

Comment: @kolistivra When you ask for some tools which is missed in Mac OS, please think about `homebrew` (The missing package manager for macOS), in most case, you can get what you need.